# Additional Drivers unknown

Tags: 16.04, dell, additional-drivers

[Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlvEd.jpg)

Can anybody tell me what the unknown:unknown driver is referring to in the picture linked above?  Or tell me how I can find out?  I am running 16.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude E5520.

There are no issues with my system as everything is running fine I am just curious to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got Intel processors, that additional driver is a good idea to use. It's actually `intel-microcode` and it upgrades the processors microcode to the latest, at each boot.